# ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.current).focus() not working with setTimeout()

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js

Not able to find `DOMNode` inside `setTimeout` function

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.current).focus();
setTimeout(()=>{
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.focusableEle).focus();   
},2000)
```

While writing mocha test cases for given lines of code, if test cases are taking more than 2 sec to execute, it is giving **Cannot read property 'focus' of null**.

What could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: It seems like this.refs is a ref object with a .current property, so accessing this.refs.focusableEle doesn’t make sense.